# ObjectMapper, Carthage, and Xcode 6.3 error

Tags: swift, xcode6, carthage

Have a project using Carthage for dependencies.  Recently updated to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2.  When that happened I also had to update my Cartfile which is now:

github "Alamofire/Alamofire" >= 1.2

github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" >= 2.2

github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 0.9

ObjectMapper does not seem to be able to compile however.  When running 'carthage update' I get:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileSwift normal x86_64 .../Carthage/Checkouts/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper/Core/Mapper.swift
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

Looks like the folks working on the ObjectMapper have included changes to support newest Swift/Xcode and don't see others with issues on that end.  Would appreciate any insight into this error message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.9 of ObjectMapper didn't include support for the swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3. If you use the latest you should be good to go:

"Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 0.11

Comment: If you are using ObjectMapper to map HTTP responses, you should consider using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). It is a simple extension to Alamofire which automatically converts your responses into swift objects using ObjectMapper. Full disclosure: I am the author of both ObjectMapper and AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: I'm using AlamofireObjectMapper for swift 1.2. Installed it using following command "pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 0.7’". but for some strange reason it is downloading 0.9 version which only supports swift 2.0 I'm in trouble with my project. Can you please tell why this happens?? Thanks

Comment: @LinkonSid if you change your podfile line to the following pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '0.7' I think that should resolve your issue. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod for details about podfile dependency syntax

Comment: that seems to work. but a problem still exists. its installing objectmapper 0.19 version. but I need 0.15 version for swift 1.2 is there any solution to this??